# Auto-saving after lsp refactor

Tags: python, doom, lsp-mode

When I use `lsp-rename` function, the edited files are not saved automatically and I have to manually save them. Is this an expected behavior and, is it possible to change this?

(I use emacs 27.2, with doom configuration. I use pyright as the lsp backend for python projects.)

edit: in [lsp-mode changelog](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/CHANGELOG/) for version 7.1 (which isn't released yet), I've found this:

> - Add lsp-auto-save-changed-buffers which save the changed buffers    after any text edit operation by lsp-mode.

But I'm pretty sure it was working correctly before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That CL line is stale, I will remove it. To achieve what you want use:

```
(add-hook 'lsp-after-apply-edits-hook
          (lambda (operation)
            (when (eq operation 'rename)
              (save-buffer))))
```

In general, I use `projectile-save-project-buffers` for this usecase.